# 2x2 matrix multiplication issue

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Let

$$f_w(z)=z+w=\begin{bmatrix}1 & w \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}z$$

where $z$ is a complex number.

Shouldn't this be $w$ when $z=0$? However when I do the multiplication I get 
$$\begin{bmatrix}(1)(0)+(w)(0)  \\ (0)(0) + (1)(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Counter-example:

Let

$$f_w(z)=z+w=\begin{bmatrix}1 & w \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}z$$

$$g_x(z)=\overline{x}z=\begin{bmatrix}\overline{x} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}z$$

Then

$$(f_w\circ g_x)(z)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & w \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\overline{x} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}z = \begin{bmatrix}\overline{x} & w \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}z$$

If $z=0$, then does this mean $(f_w\circ g_x)(z) = z\overline{x} + w = w$? This seems to be incorrect somehow because this is no different than if I had just computed $f_w(z)$ by itself on $z=0$.

Comment: In the case of $f_w\circ g_x$, $g_x$ happens first, so you multiply zero by $\overline{x}$, which in ordinary arithmetic is still zero.  $f_w$ happens next, so you add $w$ to zero.

Comment: In your counter example it matters which order of multiplication you use. Because $z$ appears on the right side, then the right most matrix will be applied first, thus the input to the left matrix will be $\bar{x}z$, which should return $\bar{x}z+w$, which is also the case. If you swap the order of the matrices you will get $\bar{x}z+\bar{x}w$.

Comment: So my order is backwards? So if I had $f_w\circ g_x \circ h_y$ I'd evaluate the $h$ matrix times the $g$ matrix times the $f$ matrix, in that order, before multiplying by $z$?

Comment: Is there no way to compute the matrix product _before_ applying it to $z$?

Comment: You could multiply $z$ by $h_y$ first, then by $g_x$, then by $f_w$.  That is the same as multiplying the matrices $f_w$ by $g_x$ by $h_y$ in that order, then multiply the product by $z$.

Comment: Yes, you did multiply the matrices correctly in your example.

Comment: It doesn't make sense then, because the first transformation is an addition and the second transformation is a rotation (in the complex plane). It doesn't make sense that I can add something to $0$ to make it nonzero, and then after rotating it, it's still in the same place as if I hadn't applied a rotation?

Comment: The order of the matrices is backwards.  The one closest to $z$ is done first, so the right-most is done first.  Your comment at 13:55:51 was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ is represented as $\left[\begin{array}{c}z\\1\end{array}\right]$, or as $\left[\begin{array}{c}2z\\2\end{array}\right]$ and so on.
So $0=\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]$, or $\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\y\end{array}\right]$ for $y\neq0$.  The vector $\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right]$ is not allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct? Using this result as you've stated I get another odd contradiction. I updated the OP